# Constructor for the structure

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have the following two C++ structures.

```
struct Vertex3D{
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat z;
    Vertex3D(GLfloat a, GLfloat b, GLfloat c){
        x = a;
        y = b;
        z = c;
    }
};

struct Triangle3D{
    Vertex3D v1;
    Vertex3D v2;
    Vertex3D v3;
    Triangle3D(Vertex3D vt1, Vertex3D vt2, Vertex3D vt3){

    };

};
```

The construtor for Vertex3D is fine but the one for Triangle3D gives me some warning and I am not being able to compile in xcode. The error says 'Constructor for 'Triangle3D'' must explicitly initialise member 'v2' which does not have default constructor'. But, I have created a constructor for the Vertex3D type of struct. What is actually wrong with this constructor in Traingle3D ? Do I need to change it, or is it not possible to create a constructor with some other struct ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But you didn't provide a DEFAULT constructor (i.e., one that can be called with no arguments).

One way to do fix this is to default all the arguments for your constructor:

```
Vertex3D(GLfloat a = 0.0, GLfloat b = 0.0, GLfloat c = 0.0){
    ...
}
```

But probably you should explicitly initialize each member of your triangle:

```
Triangle3D(Vertex3D vt1, Vertex3D vt2, Vertex3D vt3)
    : v1(vt1), v2(vt2), v3(vt3)
{
    // Probably don't need code here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean?

```
struct Triangle3D{
    Vertex3D v1;
    Vertex3D v2;
    Vertex3D v3;
    Triangle3D(Vertex3D vt1, Vertex3D vt2, Vertex3D vt3): v1(vt1),v2(vt2),v3(vt3){

    };
```